# Why should i use Future methods as opposed to Apex Queueable?

Tags: apex

With the introduction of queueable apex, is there a reason why we should opt for a future method instead?

Since we have many advantages in queueable like being able to pass sobjects or complex data types, chaining and monitoring, why should one choose future?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Future methods came first, while Queueable was an iterative evolution of future methods. The annotation is still required for backwards compatibility, but you should generally choose Queueable over future. You can still choose to use future methods if you don't care about monitoring, chaining, passing complex objects, etc. They offer no benefits except less complexity in terms of syntax (you don't need to construct an object and call a system method), but this is so trivially small a difference that I wouldn't consider it a benefit worth using.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good comparison in Salesforce's documentation, search these for "queueable" and "future"

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_async_overview.htm?search_text=future
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex

> | Async Apex Feature | When to Use |
> | --- | --- |
> | Queueable Apex | To start a long-running operation and get an ID for |
> |  | To pass complex types to a job |
> |  | To chain jobs |
> | Scheduled Apex | To schedule an Apex class to run on a specific schedule > |
> | Batch Apex | For long-running jobs with large data volumes that need to >be performed in batches, such as database maintenance jobs |
> |  | For jobs that need larger query results than regular transactions allow |
> | Future Methods | When you have a long-running method and need to >prevent delaying an Apex transaction |
> |  | When you make callouts to external Web services |
> |  | To segregate DML operations and bypass the mixed save DML error |